# How many variable can I use in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

I am a little curious about how many variable I can set in Batch File.

I have a little script here

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %%P IN (1,1,2147483647) DO (
    SET Foo[%%P]=%%P
    ECHO !Foo[%%P]!
)
```

But this script would take forever to run. So, is there any way to find out variable amount limit?
(and of course how many variable can be used in Batch file.)

EDIT:

Since comment below says that var. Amount may vary due to different OS. So if you would answer, use `Windows 7 64bit w/ 4 GB RAM` as your guideline.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think there is no hard limit for the number of variables (at least from Windows Vista onward), the only limitation is the amount of RAM; [environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx) are stored as a null-terminated list of null-terminated strings consisting of variable name, equal-to sign and variable value each, so the longer the variable names and the longer the values, the less variables can be defined...

Comment: ...there *was* a hard limit of the environment block size in MD-DOS and in older Windows versions, which I believe was 32 KiB (perhaps up to Windows XP, but I am not sure about that though); since introduction of the [`setlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)/[`endlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) commands, you can have multiple such environment blocks (I have no idea how many blocks can be defined throughout all the different Windows versions though)...

Comment: The maximum space for the environment in Win XP Pro (and probably all posterior versions) is 64 MB. See [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true) (below "Setting environment variables, Note").

Comment: If you find yourself asking *What is the absolute limit to this thing?* it usually means you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Ken White I am just a bit curious about that. But you point out the problem correctly.

Comment: @Aacini, [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is talking about a limit of 32 KiB for the environment block for Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, and for later versions, there is no technical limitation at all...

Comment: If the maximum signed 32-bit number of variables is not sufficient for your test loop, try to nest two loops...

Comment: @aschipfl that would be a better solution but I have no idea on that yet. Maybe you can do a little bit more demonstration for me, thanks

Comment: I meant something like this: `for /L %%J in (0,1,0x7FFFFFFF) do for /L %%I in (0,1,0x7FFFFFFF) do set "ARRAY[%%J_%%I]=some long text"` (the array-style variable theoretically reaches a size of 2^31 × 2^31 = 2^62 elements)

Comment: @aschipfl Now I got what you're trying to say, thanks for your help.

Comment: You may review some tests with very large environments at [this thread](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2597). An obvious problem is that the execution of the Batch file is slower as the environment is larger...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the real answer is that it depends on the limitations of your machine such as RAM, especially hard disk space, and so forth. But, I am fairly certain you are looking for the theoretical answer, not the practical answer (I would be too!).

So, for the theoretical answer, let's assume here the following (sorry if I sound sarcastic, but these are the real requirements and they're not so realistically possible):

- Your computers architecture is 64-bit (preferably Itanium class).
- You have a 128 TB hard drive with NTFS
- You have a streamlined 32 core 4THz (terahertz) processor so you can see it complete before the day you die of old age.
- You have at least and at least 384GB of RAM (if you compressed the names and used empty strings as values)
- There are only the [65807 files](https://Check.the.windows.7.installation.ISO.files) that initially come with windows 7 professional with sp1 plus your 1 batch file on your hard disk.
- There are only the [96783 registry](https://Check.the.windows.7.installation.ISO.files) indexes that initially come with windows 7 professional with sp1 on your hard disk.

So, the big limiter we encounter is how the batch variables are stored. They are addressed in an array using signed ints. This allows for a maximum of 2,147,483,647 variables stored in the memory. Now, for where the hard disk comes into play. If you would allow the hard disk to be used for batch variables, then you will need 2 batch variables to use the hard disk files as batch variables: one variable for the cache, and one in the for loop. And, now we have 4,294,967,295 extra batch variables that can be utilized. Now for the registry, assuming windows uses signed integers to index the registry, that would allow there to be a total of 2,147,483,647 registry indexes. Now, to total it all up, (2,147,483,647 - 2) + (4,294,967,295 - (65807+1)) + (2,147,483,647 - 96783) =

## 8,589,771,996

#### (Assuming fair play without c++ coding cheatzies)

Comment: thanks for your super great answers,but I seemed to find a typo. The first word of your answer should be "Well" instead of "We'll". Anyway your braveness to answer is appreciated! -Steve

Comment: What I mean by 'cheatzies' is using about 23 lines of c++ to square the theoretical limit because c++ is not what this question is about

Comment: the links you provided seems to be dead, please update them.