# What happens when too many variables are set in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, variables

Following my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298888/how-many-variable-can-i-use-in-batch-file) , I would like to know what happen when too many variables are set.

Again I have the same script, and of course, it takes forever to run.

```bat
@Echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
For /L %%P In (1,1,999999999999) Do (
    Set Foo[%%P]=%%P
    Echo !Foo[%%P]!
)
```

So again, I would like to know what would happen, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There was no need to add this as a new question. You could have appended it to your existing question on essentially the same thing. What happened when you tried it? Does that not answer your own question?

Comment: @Compo I accept your first question to me.Uhm , as the question stated, it would take forever to test. So it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Well, as Windows command processor uses 32-bit signed variables the maximum number is 2147483647. For faster increasing RAM usage I removed `Echo !Foo[%%P]!` and changed code to assign to each environment variable a string with 7500 characters length. The command process running the batch file on Windows XP SP3 x86 already several minutes takes already 158 MB RAM according to Process Explorer and sometimes RAM usage increases temporarily to more than 260 MB. I suppose this is the case when environment variables table is moved to a new, larger RAM block.

Comment: @Mofi Okay. I got it , thanks for your help

Comment: [SET performance degrades as environment size grows](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting variables conventionally then this would apply. If you do get up to 2,147,483,647 batch variables, then set one more, then the signed integer would wrap back to zero, causing all your previously set variables to be deleted, leaking a lot of memory in the process and causing a brief instant of heavy lag. However, no, this shouldn't cause a fatal windows error.

However, if you are using setx and you do get up past 2,147,483,647 total registry keys, then the whole registry would probably be deleted, permanently BSODing your computer. However, no need to fret about accidentally doing this because your computer would lag completely out as the overhead of successive registry keys are added increased. However, a reason to fret about that is the lag will persist through reboots because the registry is loaded into the ram each time the computer boots. So, **No, it is not a smart idea to test this out for yourself**. However, if you were to do this by importing a registry file into the registry, and you had enough RAM, and your computers architecture is 64-bit, then this might actually be possible...